# C program compiles, but terminates right after execution

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have a simple c program that consists of `main.c` and `selection_sort.c`.
I am compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra main.c selection_sort.c`
I get no errors of warnings, but when executed it immediately terminates without any `printf` or `system quot`. I am using Linux OS.

```
//main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void selection_sort();

int main(void) {
    printf("Program started...\n");
    selection_sort();
    printf("Selection_sort has finished...\n");

    return 0;
}


//selection_sort.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define size 10000

void selection_sort() {
    int i,j, array[size];

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int num = rand() % size;
        array[i] = num;
        printf("%d ", num);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int max_index = i;
        for(j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if(array[j] > max_index) {
                max_index = array[j];
            }
        }

        int tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[max_index];
        array[max_index] = tmp;
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < size;i++){
        printf("%d", array[i]);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Working fine to me if `selection_sort()` function is added to the `main.c` file.

Comment: In which way? Like gdb? No, i am sadly not quiet familiar with using gdb.

Comment: The program runs fine here, but it doesn't sort the array.

Comment: To fedorqui - That is the problem. This program is a school work and it is supposed to be a multi-source file program.

Comment: Can you show us an example of your running the program and nothing happening? e.g. copy/paste from terminal. It's hard to say from here.

Comment: Try extern void selection_sort(); I am not sure it will help. I have compiled your code with the same way as yours and it works fine.

Comment: It's not related to your current problem. But let it be preemptive punch before next question why your results are the same every time. You forgot to initialize random number generator. Also the title is funny, because it's normal that program terminates after execution =)

Comment: Nope random number generator works fine. Michael Walz figured it out. Yes title is kinda funny :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -c selection_sort.c
gcc -o myprog main.o selection_sort.o
./myprog
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot this one helped.

Comment: What did **you** do to launch your program once yo've compiled it ?

Comment: What's the difference between this and gcc selection_sort.c main.c -o myprog? thx

Comment: @notbad: actually none

Comment: @MichaelWalz So the problem is he didn't run ./a.out?:)

Comment: @notbad: something like that, or ./ is not in his path.

Answer (score 0):

you should use for compilation:

```
    gcc -o main  main.c selection_sort.c -Wall -Wextra
```